# Why after using the split command it deletes all data from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

From an itertuple loop, I read in some row values and then converted the values read into Series data, then changed the astype to a string and used concat to add it to dff and  as shown below.

```
In [24]: dff
Out[24]: 
    SRD                     Aspectno
0  9450           [9450.01, 9450.02]
1  9880  [9880.01, 9880.02, 9880.03]
```

When I apply the following command line, it strips out all the data. I have used the split command before, It may have something to do with the square brackets, but using str.strip or str(0), also removes all the data.

```
In [25]: splitdff = dff['Aspectno'].str.split(',', expand = True)

In [26]: splitdff
Out[26]: 
    0
0 NaN
1 NaN
```

What am I doing wrong?
Also, when converting the data read after reading the rows, how do I get data in row 0 to be shifted to the left, i.e, [9450.01, 9450.02] shift over to the left by one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to split a list on a comma, that's a method intended for strings.  Try this to break the values out into their own columns:

```
 import pandas as pd

 ...

 dff['Aspectno'].apply(pd.Series)
```

It will give you a DataFrame with the entries in columns.  The lists are different lengths, so there will be a number of columns equal to the length of the longest list.  If you know that length you could do this:

```
dff[['col1','col2','col3']] = dff['Aspectno'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: Mr. Wizard, that worked!. Now I should able to use melt on the data. I just started learning Python a few weeks ago and recall the apply method in a tutorial. So much to remember. Anyways thanks, I thought I converted the series data into a string using this;  serasp.astype(str), but dtype info reports it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

The code `dff['Aspectno']` select the series `Aspectno`, so `[9450.02, 9880.03]` and the split on character `,` doesn't do anything, as there are no commas in the series values.

Comment: But in Excel if I write dff to a worksheet, [9450.02, 9880.03] appears in one Excel. This should be no different when I would read in data from a cell with multiple line returns contained in the cell. I read the date into a dataframe and then split the values using '\n' and it works fine.

Comment: According to the locale that you are in, Excel may use `,` or `;` as separators.